# Prove that intervals of the form $(a,b]$, $[a,b)$, $(-\infty,a]$, $[a,\infty)$ do not have the fixed point property.

Tags: general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Prove that intervals of the form $(a,b]$, $[a,b)$, $(-\infty,a]$, $[a,\infty)$ do not have the fixed point property.

In the case of open intervals, I can derive that they do not have the fixed point property by the fact that the real line doesn't have this property. But how can I show this in these kinds of half intervals?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1866054/show-that-the-only-intervals-having-the-fixed-point-property-are-the-closed-inte

Answer (score 1):

Let's take one of them for example: the first one, $(a,b]$.

Say, for simplicity, that $a=0$ and $b=1$.  Now take the function $x\mapsto \frac x2$.  It is continuous, from $(a,b]$ to $(a,b]$, but does not have fixed points.

Comment: What about the case in which a and b are arbitrary? We cant use the function x/2 so what can we take as the function?

Comment: @user135204 Simply take the function $x\mapsto \frac {x-a}2 + a$.

Comment: @user135204: but $(a,b]$ "looks like" $(0,1]$. So you just have to express precisely what it means for them to "look alike", and then the function that looks like $x \mapsto x/2$ is exactly what you want. Or, figure out "why" this example works for $(0,1]$, and then use the same idea for arbitrary $(a,b]$.